# implementation of stl copy function?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, std

Here is some implementation details of the std::copy function(from vs2015):

```
template<class _InIt,
    class _OutIt> inline
    _OutIt _Copy_impl(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last,
        _OutIt _Dest, _Scalar_ptr_iterator_tag)
    {   // copy [_First, _Last) to [_Dest, ...), pointers to scalars
    ptrdiff_t _Count = _Last - _First;
    _CSTD memmove(&*_Dest, &*_First,
        _Count * sizeof (*_First));
    return (_Dest + _Count);
    }
```

It seems that we can just use the memmove in case of scalar type.But why can't we use memmove if it is POD type (C++11)?As far as I know, it's both trivial and
standard layout.

Comment: *"But why can't we use memmove if it is POD type"* You've shown one of the implementations of `std::copy`, but not the tag dispatching. What version is chosen for PODs instead, and how is the tag dispatching implemented?

Comment: libc++ uses `is_trivially_copy_assignable` (and an additional minor type check) to dispatch `std::copy` to `memmove`.

Comment: @dyp libstdc++ essentially uses  `__is_trivial(_ValueTypeI)`. A bit confusing, as there are trivially copy assignable classes that aren't trivial classes.

Comment: @dyp I have looked at MSVC2013, and it really uses only scalar_tag to perform `memmove`. Moreover, this tag is set only for `is_scalar<_Elem>::value`.

Answer (score 2):

The particular requirement is "trivially copyable".

> For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to
>   distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, where neither `obj1` nor
>   `obj2` is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making
>   up `obj1` are copied into `obj2`, 43 `obj2` shall subsequently hold
>   the same value as `obj1`.
>
> <sub>43) By using, for example, the library functions (17.6.1.2)
>   `std::memcpy` or `std::memmove`.</sub>

This is, amongst others, met by PODs and scalars. But VC++' requirement is narrower than necessary. So is libstdc++', who requires the type to be entirely trivial. Solely libc++ tests for `is_trivially_copy_assignable`.